# My random string generator in C doesn't work

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

void randomGenerator(char *id, int length);
int main(){
    char test[8];
    randomGenerator(&test[0],strlen(test));
    printf("%s",test);

}
void randomGenerator(char *id, int length){
    char alphabet[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char *gen;
    gen = &alphabet[0];
    for (int i = 0;i<length-1;i++){
        srand(time(0));
        int random = rand() % strlen(alphabet);
        for (int k = 0; i < random;i++)
            gen++;
        id = gen;
        gen = &alphabet[0];
        id++;
    }
    id++;
    id = '\0';
}
```

My attempt of random string generator failed but I have literally no idea why, could someone please help me?
When I compile it what I get as output is nothing, no string or no characters on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two major problems:

- You use `strlen(test)` before the contents of the array is initialized, which means the contents is indeterminate and may not contain a null-terminator at all. Use `sizeof test` to get the size (in bytes) of the array.
- In the `randomGenerator` function you don't actually write to the elements of the array, instead you reassign the pointer. An assignment like `id = gen` reassigns the pointer, it doesn't write to where the pointer is pointing. For that you need to dereference the pointer, as in `*id = *gen`.

And a minor problem: You call `srand` in the loop. That will reset the seed *every iteration*, and if seeded with the same number (very likely here) then the `rand` function *will* return the same value. You should only seed the random number generator *once*.

Comment: Now I changed the strlen section and the pointers but now it just generates a string full of same characters that's not what I want

Comment: @emirhan422 Updated answer with the probable problem (and solution) for that.